# UIView rotate and then move

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have problem with rotating and moving image (UIView).

If I use this for rotate:

```
[UIView beginAnimations: @"rotate" contex: nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration: 1];
[UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState: YES];
[UIView setAnimationCurve: UIViewAnimationCurveLinear];
spaceShip.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation (angle); // spaceShip is the UIView
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

And this to move:

```
[UIView beginAnimations: @"move" contex: nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration: 1];
[UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState: YES];
[UIView setAnimationCurve: UIViewAnimationCurveLinear];
spaceShip.center = destanation // destanation is a point where user tap
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

It's working well one at a time. But together this two animations don't work. Space Ship is rotating, but does not move in direction.

Where my mistake?

**P.S.** Early I have specify anchor point (0.5, 0.5). But when I rotate image it coordinates is changing.

**UPD:**

Used block-based methods. Like this

```
- (void) viewDidLoad
{
    [spaceShip.layer setAnchorPoint: CGPointMake(0.5, 0.5)];

}

- (void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *tap = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
    destanationPoint = [tap locationInView: tap.view];

    NSLog(@"%0.3f", angle*180/M_PI);//Just for monitoring

    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0
                          delay: 0.0
                        options: UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut
                     animations:^{
                         spaceShip.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(angle);
                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished){
                         // Wait one second and then fade in the view
                         [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0
                                               delay: 1.0
                                             options: UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut
                                          animations:^{
                                              spaceShip.center = destanationPoint;
                                          }
                                          completion:nil];
                     }];

}
```

That method is working. But every new tap UIImage change coordinates at starting position. Ok, i tried add:

```
options: UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut |
         UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState
```

but it isn't help.

**UPD2**

Try do this:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0

                          delay: 0.0
                        options: UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut |
                                UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState
                     animations:^{
                         spaceShip.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(angle);
                         spaceShip.center = destanationPoint;
                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished){
                         // Wait one second and then fade in the view
                         [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0
                                               delay: 1.0
                                             options: UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut |
                                                    UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState
                                          animations:^{
                                              spaceShip.center = destanationPoint;
                                          }
                                          completion:nil];
                     }];
```

Now my ship rotate and move to tap point. In second tap in another point UIView return in starting coordinate, but....with animation ))

Comment: Hm, try doing `spaceShip.center = destanationPoint;` in your completion block (even if the BOOL argument is NO) as well as your animation block.  If that doesn't work, I'll have to do some more looking into animations to be able to help you.

Comment: In such cases the easiest way would be to place ship view into another UIView. set movement animation to ship view parent view, and rotation to ship view.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to Stack Overflow :)

If you read the [UIView Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html):

> Changes to several view properties can be animated—that is, changing
>   the property creates an animation that conveys the change to the user
>   over a short period of time. The UIView class does most of the work of
>   performing the actual animations but you must still indicate which
>   property changes you want to be animated. There are two different ways
>   to initiate animations:

- In iOS 4 and later, use the block-based animation methods. **(Recommended)**
- Use the begin/commit animation methods.

> The block-based animation methods (such as
>   animateWithDuration:animations:) greatly simplify the creation of
>   animations. With one method call, you specify the animations to be
>   performed and the options for the animation. However, block-based
>   animations are available only in iOS 4 and later. If your application
>   runs on earlier versions of iOS, you must use the
>   beginAnimations:context: and commitAnimations class methods to mark
>   the beginning and ending of your animations.

So I would recommend switching to the block method, as it's definitely easier to work with.

Here are some good links that cover the subject:

- [Apple Docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/windowsviews/conceptual/viewpg_iphoneos/animatingviews/animatingviews.html)
- [Ray Wenderlich](http://www.raywenderlich.com/2454/how-to-use-uiview-animation-tutorial)
- [Ho.Race.Uk](http://ho.race.hk/blog/2010/07/animating-views-with-blocks-example/)

Now, specifically for your problem, have you tried putting rotation and movement into the same animation block?  It might be that the two are canceling each other out, especially since you use `[UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState: YES];` which I believe interrupts whatever animation is currently occurring.

Comment: Thank you! I try use block-based methods. And it work. But...every time when I tap again UIView start animations from starting state, from starting coordinates. Also try use options: UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Can you post your new code?  And not just the animation block, the code around it--anywhere that deals with the variables that are being handled in the animation block.

Answer (score 0):

try like this,

```
{
    [UIView beginAnimations: @"rotate" contex: nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration: 1];
    [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState: YES];
    [UIView setAnimationCurve: UIViewAnimationCurveLinear];
    spaceShip.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation (angle); // spaceShip is the UIView
    [UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector: @selector(animationStopped)];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

then,

```
-(void)animationStopped {
[UIView beginAnimations: @"move" contex: nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration: 1];
[UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState: YES];
[UIView setAnimationCurve: UIViewAnimationCurveLinear];
spaceShip.center = destanation // destanation is a point where user tap
[UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

Comment: Thanks but result is same. It rotate, but don't move. I try put NSLog(@"test") in method animationStopped - this text don't display.

Answer (score 0):

it is simple code for set animation in UIView

```
// transform make rotation for the view
     view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI_2*1);
         [UIView commitAnimations];  

    // it used to move view with animation
    [UIView animateWithDuration:2
                              delay:1.0
                            options: UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut
                         animations:^{
                            //set your new frame for UIView
                         } 
                         completion:^(BOOL finished){
                             NSLog(@"Done!");
                         }];
```

Answer (score 0):

just replace

```
spaceShip.center = destination
```

with

`spaceShip.center = CGPointMake(destination.x, destination.y);`

**UPD**

and add NSLOG (after CGPoint destination)

```
- (void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *tap = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
    CGPoint destanation = [tap locationInView: tap.view];
    NSLog(@" x=%f and y=%f", destination.x, destination.y
          );
```

Comment: Thanks, but nope. It isn't change anythink.

Comment: just for monitorig... try "code"  NSLog(@" x= %f and y=%f", destination.x, destination.y
          );

Answer (score 0):

Try to uncheck "use Autolayout" in your ViewController (Identity and Type) in Storyboard.

I had the same problem, and this resolves mine.